# Rails5｜Uncaught TypeError: $(...).froalaEditor is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, froala

I'm using rails5.0.6 and trying to add Froala editor to my project.

In development it works fine,but in production Froala does not work and result is

> new:107 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).froalaEditor is not a function

To solve this problem,　I did

- rails assets:precompile rails_env=production
- In production.rb,rewrite config.assets.compile = true

but I do not solve.

In my assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require main/bootstrap.min
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/colors.min
//= require plugins/font_size.min
//= require plugins/char_counter.min
//= require languages/ja
//= require_tree ./main
```

In my articles/new 107:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
$('#wysiwyg').froalaEditor({     
  language: 'ja',      
  toolbarButtons: ['bold','strikeThrough','fontSize']
});
});
</script>
```

In my config/production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
config/application.rb.

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false


  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```